# TLS Authentication on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, tls1.2

Does Google Cloud Platform has Mutual TLS Authentication, like for example AWS does ?

Answer (score 1):

Google provides Application Layer Transport Security (ALTS) which has a  secure handshake protocol similar to mutual TLS. Two services wishing to communicate using ALTS employ this handshake protocol to authenticate and negotiate communication parameters before sending any sensitive information. The protocol is a two-step process: Handshake and Record encryption[image: ALTS Process]

For more on this, please refer to [ALTS Protocol](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-in-transit/).